# Control Statements: Why is my 'New Balance' change when I 'charge to credit' then 'pay credit' twice?

Tags: java, while-loop, switch-statement, calculator, credits

I tried reading from the start of this Java book and do some of its exercises for summer vacation. The I came up with this problem:
"*(Credit Limit Calculator) Develop a Java application that determines whether any of several
department-store customers has exceeded the credit limit on a charge account.....For those customers whose credit limit is exceeded, the program should display
the message "Credit limit exceeded".*"

My code works only if I use Charge to Credit ONCE. If I use Charge to Credit again, my new balance value will change. Example:

> ```
> * Acc # = 123
> * Beginning Balance = 20000
> * Credit Limit = 25000
> * Select Transaction = 1 (Charge to Credit)
> * Amount to charge = 4000
> * Select Transaction = 2 (Pay credit)
> * Amount to pay = 2000 [My balance should now be 22000)
> * Select Transaction = 1 (Charge to Credit)
> * Amount to charge = 10000 [This shud exceed credit limit]
> * Select Transaction = 3 (Balance Inquiry)
> * My new balance is now 18000
> ```
>
> This is my problem now. My new balance should still be 22000 since the credit limit has exceeded. But now its 18000. I don't know where it went wrong so I need help, please.

So here's my code:

**Customer.java**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Customer {

Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);

int accNum,
    beginBal,
    creditLimit;

int itemsCharged,
    creditsPaid,
    newBalance;

int transaction;
String action;

public void start (){
    System.out.print("\nAccount Number: ");
    accNum = input.nextInt();

    System.out.print("Beginning Balance: ");
    beginBal = input.nextInt();

    System.out.print("Credit Limit: ");
    creditLimit = input.nextInt();

    transaction();
}

public void transaction (){

    boolean loop = true;
    while (loop){
        System.out.println("\n[1] Charge to Credit \n[2] Pay Credit \n[3] Balance Inquiry/Exit");
        System.out.print("Select Transaction #: ");

        transaction = input.nextInt();

        switch (transaction){
        case 1:
            System.out.print("\n--CHARGE TO CREDIT-- \nEnter amount: ");
            itemsCharged = input.nextInt();

            newBalance = beginBal + itemsCharged - creditsPaid;
            if (newBalance > creditLimit){
                System.err.println("Credit Limit Exceeded!");
                newBalance -= itemsCharged;
            } else {
                System.out.println("Amount charged.");
            }
            break;
        case 2:
            System.out.print("\n--PAY CREDIT-- \nEnter amount: ");
            creditsPaid = input.nextInt();

            newBalance = beginBal + itemsCharged - creditsPaid;
            if (creditsPaid > newBalance){
                System.err.println("Invalid Amount!");
                newBalance -= creditsPaid;
            } else {
                System.out.println("Payment posted!");
                newBalance = beginBal + itemsCharged - creditsPaid;
            }
            break;
        case 3:
            System.out.println("\n--BALANCE INQUIRY-- \nNew Balance: " + newBalance);
            restart();
            break;
        default:
            System.err.println("Invalid number!");
            transaction();
            break;
        }
    }
}

public void restart (){

    System.out.println("\nDo you have another transaction? [Y/N]");
    System.out.print("Select Action: ");

    boolean loop = true;
    while (loop){

        action = input.nextLine();

        switch (action){
        case "Y":
            start();
            break;
        case "N":
            System.err.println("Terminated.");
            System.exit(0);
            break;
        }
    }
}

} // end class
```

**CreditLimitCal.java**

```
public class CreditLimitCal {
public static void main (String[] args){

    Customer cus = new Customer();

    cus.start();

}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this line:

```
newBalance = beginBal + itemsCharged - creditsPaid;
```

Doesn't need to subtract `creditsPayed`, you've already done that previously when the user paid off part of the balance.

newBalance should only be modified by one thing each time, so for case 1:

```
newBalance = newBalance + itemsCharged;
```

case 2:

```
newBalance = newBalance - creditsPaid;
```

Comment: But that's also in case 1. So if I remove that, then my newbalance will get bigger and bigger discarding the credits paid. :-/

Comment: It worked, thanks! But then when I continue to "Do you have another transaction?" and enter another account num, with 10000 beginning balance and 15000 credit limit. then I charge to credit for the first time on that account, it says "Credit limit exceeded". Then the balance will be the previous balance from acc num 123.

Comment: @javanerd in start() you should set newBal to beginBal and reset the other values.

Comment: Now it's good! Thank you sooo much! I could now rest in peace. Lol